# How to fix GraphicsEnvironment.getRefreshRate() returning wrong value

Tags: java, linux

I've been trying to obtain the refresh rate of the primary display in java via the GraphicsEnvironment class. For some reason on my desktop(single 165HZ monitor), it's returning 50 as my refresh rate instead of 165. On my 60HZ laptop, it's returning 60 just fine. Both are Linux(laptop LM, PC Manjaro), and I'm not sure why it's not working properly on my PC but just fine on my laptop.

Here are the file and results:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

class FileName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hrz = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate();

        System.out.println(hrz);
    }
}
```

```
[shringe@dashingkoso Refresh-Rate]$ javac FileName.java
[shringe@dashingkoso Refresh-Rate]$ java FileName
50
[shringe@dashingkoso Refresh-Rate]$
```

Any idea on why this is happening, or how I could fix this?

edit:

The output of "xrandr -q" shows my display info and the * shows that 165HZ is selected under 2560x1440.

```
DP-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 + 165.00*  160.00   155.00   143.97   120.00  
   1920x1080    119.88   100.00    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think you should get 165?

Comment: tgdavies because I'm using a 165HZ monitor.

Comment: Monitors can usually be driven at a range of frequencies -- that 165Hz is probably the maximum the monitor can do, rather than the only frequency you can drive it at.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have 50 Hz ? Your monitor is able to refresh 165 times per second but that doesn't mean it actually does it all the time

Comment: mi1000 and tgdavies, I added the output of "xrandr -q" to the post proving that it is set to 165HZ.

Comment: Why do you want to know? This seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725); you want to know the native display refresh rate **because** that will allow you to do what?

Comment: Elliott Frisch I am using this to automatically set the framerate of my game but it is returning the wrong value on my PC.

Comment: @Shringe_ I find it highly unlikely that you can redraw 165 times a second in Java.

Comment: Elliot Frisch my game is in very early development and I have a good computer so uncapped it reaches many thousands; However, the GraphicsEnvironment.getRefrshRate() function is returning the wrong value so it's being capped at 60 on my PC rather than 165 which would be correct.